# Sql query wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-division

Hi i have the following database schema

```
Professor (EMP ID,Name,Status,Salary,Age)
Course(Course ID,Course Name,PoINts)
Works(Course ID,EMP ID,Class ID)
```

I have written the following query to Return list of employees who have taught course M1 or M2 but NOT both

```
SELECT p.empid,p.name
FROM professor p,course c,works w
WHERE p.empid = w.empid
AND w.courseid = c.courseid
AND ((c.coursename = ‘m1’ AND c.coursename != ‘m2’)
OR
(c.coursename = ‘m2’ AND c.coursename != ‘m1’))
```

Is the above query right as i am new to sql please help

Comment: Rather than asking StackOverflow with the hope someone answer it fast without you having to spend the effort, you can use sqlfiddle.com to find the answer yourself

Comment: ...and if sqlfiddle doesn't yield a result, publish the link here and at least we will have something to code against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually termed as `Relational Division`. What the query below does is it gets all the professor's name which teaches the courses such as `m1` and `m2`. After the professors has been filtered it then counts the number of distinct `CourseName`. Obviously, it will return one if it only teaches one course `:D`.

```
SELECT  a.EmpID, a.Name
FROM    Professor a
        INNER JOIN Works b
            ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
        INNER JOIN  Course c
            ON b.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE   c.CourseName IN ('m1', 'm2')
GROUP   BY a.EmpID, a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.CourseName) = 1
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: i'll be waiting for your feedback, if this doesn't please provide sample data along with your question. thanks `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT p.empid,p.name
FROM professor p join works w on
p.empid = w.empid
having count(w.courseid) = 2
```

This assumes you have 2 classes total, which, while unlikely, it will point you in the right direction.